# C - Storing an int pointer in an integer

Tags: c, pointers, 64-bit, integer

I have any array of type int and need to store, within this array, a pointer to another part of the array.

The problem is that, on 64bit systems, the size of the pointer is 8 bytes, and the size of the int is 4 bytes causing complier warnings (e.g. warning cast to pointer from integer of different size)

I (think0 i understand why the complier is moaning, obviously trying to fit 8 bytes into 4 bytes isn't a clever idea. The problem is the array is supplied to me as is and I must use only the array for storage.

Comment: can you explain how you would later read the array, in a way that you could distinguish the elements that are pointers from the elements that are ints?

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 6):

If you are referring to the same array, why don't you store just the index?

```
#include <limits>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

int array[ARRAY_DIMENSION];

/**
 * the following line will cause an error at compile-time if size_t
 * is not enough to index the array.
 */

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() >= ARRAY_DIMENSION);

int access_array(size_t index)
{
    size_t intended_index = array[index];
    return array[intended_index];
}
```

Comment: And note that again, on a 64 bit system you might not be able to fit the index into an `int`. You could fit it into two `int`, though, high and low parts (or, in general, however many ints needed on the platform, but anyone asking this question isn't writing generally portable code).

Comment: Yes, the OP could check the array's size at compile time.

Comment: For an index into an array to be too big to fit a 32 bit unsigned integer, the array (containing at least an unsigned int for each element) would take a minimum of 16 Gigabytes.  This is not impossible on a 64 bit system, but unlikely.  Anyway, instead of `int`, use `size_t` and the problem goes away.

Comment: The assertion should not be required, since `size_t` is defined to be large enough to hold the size of *any* object, and the size of `array` must be `>= ARRAY_DIMENSION`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that can't be done. As you correctly deduced, you can't fit a 64-bit value into a 32-bit one. You would have to be supplied an array of [intptr_t](http://www.viva64.com/en/t/0023/) for that to work.

Comment: +1 for using the C99 type explicitly designed for this. Be sure to `#include <stdint.h>` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store pointers in `int`s.  Store pointers in pointer variables.  If you really need to do this, consider using an array of unions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a struct.

```
struct myint
{
    int array[10];
    int *next;
};
```